# Flannel is crashing for Slave node

Tags: kubernetes

I am getting this result for flannel service on my slave node.  Flannel is running fine on master node.

```
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-amd64-xbtrf      0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   4          3m5s
```

Kube-proxy running on the slave is fine but not the flannel pod.

I have a master and a slave node only.  At first its say `running`, then it goes to `error` and finally, `crashloopbackoff`.

```
godfrey@master:~$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o wide
NAMESPACE     NAME                             READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE     IP                NODE     NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-amd64-jszwx      0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   4          2m17s   192.168.152.104   slave3   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-proxy-hxs6m                 1/1     Running            0          18m     192.168.152.104   slave3   <none>           <none>
```

I am also getting this from the logs:

```
I0515 05:14:53.975822       1 main.go:390] Found network config - Backend type: vxlan
I0515 05:14:53.975856       1 vxlan.go:121] VXLAN config: VNI=1 Port=0 GBP=false Learning=false DirectRouting=false
E0515 05:14:53.976072       1 main.go:291] Error registering network: failed to acquire lease: node "slave3" pod cidr not assigned
I0515 05:14:53.976154       1 main.go:370] Stopping shutdownHandler...
```

I could not find a solution so far.  Help appreciated.

Comment: Please give us some more details. What is your Kubernetes version? Flannel Version? It was working and stop working or it never worked?

Comment: How did you create the kubernetes cluster? If kubeadm is used you will have to pass the pod CIDR when running kubeadm init. As per the official flannel https://github.com/coreos/flannel/blob/master/Documentation/kubernetes.md.

This might also help : https://github.com/coreos/flannel/issues/728

Comment: Hi All, thank you for jumping into help.  I solved the problem.  podCIDR subnet info was not passed to slave nodes via the "kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=172.168.10.0/24" command.  I had to do a "kubectl patch node slave1 -p '{"spec":{"podCIDR":"172.168.10.0/24"}}'" to get it working.

Comment: @GodfreyTan, please, post your solution as an answer so others can find the solution if they face similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

As solution came from OP, I'm posting answer as community wiki.

As reported by OP in the comments, he didn't passed the podCIDR during kubeadm init.

The following command was used to see that the flannel pod was in "CrashLoopBackoff" state:

```
sudo kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o wide
```

To confirm that podCIDR was not passed to flannel pod `kube-flannel-ds-amd64-ksmmh` that was in `CrashLoopBackoff` state.

```
$ kubectl logs kube-flannel-ds-amd64-ksmmh
```

`kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=172.168.10.0/24` didn't pass the podCIDR to the slave nodes as expected.

Hence to solve the problem, `kubectl patch node slave1 -p '{"spec":{"podCIDR":"172.168.10.0/24"}}'` command had to be used to pass podCIDR to each slave node.

Please see this link: [coreos.com/flannel/docs/latest/troubleshooting.html](http://coreos.com/flannel/docs/latest/troubleshooting.html) and section "Kubernetes Specific"

Comment: Yes the above solution is what I used to solved the problem.  I also used:
"sudo kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o wide" to see that the flannel pod was in "CrashLoopBackoff" state.

I used "$ kubectl logs kube-flannel-ds-amd64-ksmmh" to confirm that podCIDR was not passed to flannel pod "kube-flannel-ds-amd64-ksmmh" that was in "CrashLoopBackoff" state.

Comment: "kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=172.168.10.0/24" didn't pass the podCIDR to the slave nodes as expected.  Hence to solve the problem, "kubectl patch node slave1 -p '{"spec":{"podCIDR":"172.168.10.0/24"}}'" command had to be used to pass podCIDR to each slave node.

Please see this link: https://coreos.com/flannel/docs/latest/troubleshooting.html and section "Kubernetes Specific".

Answer (score 1):

The described cluster configuration doesn't look correct in two aspects:

---

First of all, `PodCIDR` reasonable minimum subnet size is `/16`. Each Kubernetes node usually gets `/24` subnet because it can run up to 100 pods.
`PodCIDR` and `ServicesCIDR` (default: "10.96.0.0/12") must not interfere with your existing LAN network and with each other.

So, correct `kubeadm` command would look like:

```
$ sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16
```

In your case `PodCIDR` subnet is only `/24` and it was assigned to master node. Slave node didn't get its own `/24` subnet, so Flannel Pod showed the error in the logs:

```
Error registering network: failed to acquire lease: node "slave3" pod cidr not assigned
```

Assigning the same subnet to several nodes manually will lead to the other connectivity problems.

You can find more details on Kubernetes IP subnets in [GKE documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/flexible-pod-cidr).

---

The second problem is the IP subnet number.

Recent [Calico](https://docs.projectcalico.org/getting-started/kubernetes/quickstart) network addon versions are able to detect the correct Pod subnet based on `kubeadm` parameter `--pod-network-cidr`. Older version was using predefined subnet `192.168.0.0/16` and you had to adjust it in its YAML file in the `Deaemonset` specification :

```
         - name: CALICO_IPV4POOL_CIDR
           value: "192.168.0.0/16"
```

[Flannel](https://github.com/coreos/flannel/blob/master/Documentation/kubernetes.md#kubeadm) is still requires default subnet ( `10.244.0.0/16` ) to be specified for `kubeadm init`.
To use custom subnet for your cluster, `Flannel` "installation" YAML file should be adjusted before applying to the cluster.

```
...
---
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: kube-flannel-cfg
  namespace: kube-system
...
  net-conf.json: |
    {
      "Network": "10.244.0.0/16",
      "Backend": {
        "Type": "vxlan"
      }
    }
...
```

So the following should work for any version of Kubernetes and Calico:

```
$ sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16
$ mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
$ sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
$ sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config

# Latest Calico version
$ kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/manifests/calico.yaml

# or specific version, v3.14 in this case, which is also latest at the moment
# kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.14/manifests/calico.yaml
```

Same for Flannel:

```
$ sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16
$ mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
$ sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
$ sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config

# For Kubernetes v1.7+ 
$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml    

# For older versions of Kubernetes:
# For RBAC enabled clusters:
$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/k8s-manifests/kube-flannel-rbac.yml
$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/k8s-manifests/kube-flannel-legacy.yml
$
```

There are many other network addons. You can find the list in the documentation:

- [Cluster Networking](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/)
- [Installing Addons](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/addons/#networking-and-network-policy)